# Why is my where condition in Linq query not working properly?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query where i have the following where condition:

```
where obj.DATUMREAL == date && (real == 2 ? true : (obj.ZAPKONC == null ? 0 : ((bool)obj.ZAPKONC ? 1 : 0)) == real)
```

If I set parameter `real` to 2, it works normally, but if I set it to 1 or 0 the where statement just ignores the first condition `obj.DATUMREAL == date` and it only filters with the second part after the &&.

Here is the whole query:

```
var result = (from obj in entities.OBJKVPOPLANU
              where obj.DATUMREAL == date 
                    && (real == 2 ? 
                           true : (obj.ZAPKONC == null ? 0 
                                      : ((bool)obj.ZAPKONC ? 1 : 0)) == real)
              group obj by obj.VODSISTEM into objg
              join v in entities.SIVODSISTEM 
              on objg.FirstOrDefault().VODSISTEM equals v.SIFRA.ToString()   
              into vj
              from subpet in vj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  subpet.SIFRA,
                  STEV = objg.Count(),
                  subpet.NAZIV
              }).ToList();
              return result;
```

If I set `real` value to 2 I get 30 items returned which are filtered by the first part of where, but if I set it to 1 or 0 I get more items that completely ignore the first part of where.

**UPDATE**

I solved it by swapping the two parts of the `where statement` around. I don't know what the issue was

Comment: This can't happen. Due to the short-circuit logic of operator && (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators), if the first operand is evaluated to false, the whole expression would be false. It would be helpful, if you could add the whole LINQ query, the input and what is the expected output.

Comment: @Christos I understand that && operator automaticaly ignores the second part if the first one is false, that's why i'm confused how can the first part be ignored at all.

Comment: Your code would probably be a lot more readable if you split this out; you don't have to build an entire linq query in one go, just do a `IEnumerable<whatever> x; if(blahblah) x= entities.OBJKVPOPLANU.Where(thing a) else x = entities.OBJKVPOPLANU.Where(thing b); var result = x. ...`